# How to find the minimum value of the expression? $\sqrt{(x-0,5)^2+0,75}+\sqrt{(x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2+0,25}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Help me with this. What is the minimum value of this expression I do not know how to do that. $\sqrt{(x-0,5)^2+0,75}+\sqrt{(x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2+0,25}$       ?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Interpret the given expression as the sum of two distances between points in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

[1] Differentiate the function $f(x)$ w.r.t  $x$ which will give you $\frac{d(fx)}{d x}$, and then equate it to zero, and then solve for $x$

[2] now differentiate the same differntiated function again w.r.t to $x$ i,e $\frac{d^2 f(x)}{d x^2}$and plug in the $x$ value from step 1 to see if the value is greater than 0, if it is , it is the minimum value.